# Socket communication for inter-WebRole communications in Azure

Tags: c#, sockets, azure, tcp, cloud

I'm trying to make a simple client-server in Azure. I have the client in one webrole and the server in another, and both belong to the same tenant. 
I want to use simple socket communication between the two to send a dummy file from client to server.

Here is how I wrote my app (some code removed for clarity):

1- Define "internal" tcp endpoints for each role. Assume server's port is 9000. Client's port is 9010.

2- The client sends a dummy file to the server as follows:

```
byte[] buffer = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
mSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.IP);
mSocket.Connect(IPAddress.Parse(serverIPString), 9000);
mSocket.Send(buffer);
```

3- On the server, I do the following:

```
IPEndPoint ipEnd = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 9000);
mSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.IP);
mSocket.Bind(ipEnd);
mSocket.Listen(BACKLOG);
Socket socket = mSocket.Accept();
byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
int byteCount = socket.Receive(buffer);
```

Everything works fine locally in the Azure emulator, but when I go to the cloud the server doesn't get any connections :(

Please help!

Addendum:

Someone asked how I find my endpoints. 
I display my endpoints on the main page of the server as follows and let the sender/client specify the IP they want to send the file to in a textbox.

```
foreach (var instance in RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.Role.Instances)
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, RoleInstanceEndpoint> pair in instance.InstanceEndpoints)
                addresses += "[" + pair.Key + "] " + pair.Value.IPEndpoint.Address + ":" + pair.Value.IPEndpoint.Port + ", ";
```

Comment: "Nothing works" is really unspecific. If there's an exception, tell us what it is. Is it on the server side or the client? Also, it would help if you showed where `serverIPString` is coming from. (Where's the code that finds the internal endpoint?)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. No there is no exception (as I mentioned, it works fine locally). The server just doesn't get any connections from the sender/client.

Comment: Also, I added a description concerning endpoints in addendum. Thanks!

Comment: If the server gets no connections, then what's happening on the client? Does it get an exception? Is it timing out?

Answer (score 0):

Your server needs to be in a loop waiting for a connection.  I'm not sure if you just summarized that out for your sample code, or if that is what is missing.  Your use of the Socket interface looks correct as far as the order in which you are invoking its operations.

Hope this helps http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6y0e13d3.aspx

Addendum: Nevermind, just noticed Socket.Accept() suspends so shouldn't have the problem I was thinking of when I looked at it.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a network/IP issue like a firewall or the code not recognizing the IPs and not letting communication through.

Comment: This is what I was expecting. Let's see if someone ran into the same problem and found a solution for this, it's killing me.. Thanks anyways!